# What do this methods do?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, max

I've found two diferent methods to get a Max value from an array but I'm not really fond of parallel programing, so I really don't understand it.

I was wondering do this methods do the same or am I missing something?
I really don't have much information about them. Not even comments...

The first method:

```
int[] vec = ... (I guess the content doesn't matter)

static int naiveMax()
{
    int max = vec[0];
    object obj = new object();

    Parallel.For(0, vec.Length, i =>
    {
        lock (obj) {
                if (vec[i] > max) max = vec[i];
        }
    });

    return max;
}
```

And the second one:

```
static int Max()
{
    int max = vec[0];
    object obj = new object();

    Parallel.For(0, vec.Length,     //could be Parallel.For<int>
        () => vec[0],
        (i, loopState, partial) =>
    {
        if(vec[i]>partial) partial = vec[i];
        return partial;
    },
    partial => {
            lock (obj) {
                    if( partial > max) max = partial;
            }
    });
    return max;
}
```

Do these do the same or something diferent and what? Thanks ;)

Comment: Looks to me like there would be a huge amount of spinning on those locks :/ Why don't you try them both and see the difference?

Comment: Both methods waste a lot of resources by forcing parallelized code to run sequentially.

Comment: Even without locks (that make code sequential so not parallel at all) such small computation isn't best suited for parallel execution. Overhead will be higher that the time used for computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both find the maximum value in an array of integers. In an attempt to find the maximum value faster, they do it "in parallel" using the [Parallel.For Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx). Both methods fail at this, though.

To see this, we first need a sufficiently large array of integers. For small arrays, parallel processing doesn't give us a speed-up anyway.

```
int[] values = new int[100000000];
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    values[i] = random.Next();
}
```

Now we can run the two methods and see how long they take. Using an appropriate performance measurement setup ([Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx), array of 100,000,000 integers, 100 iterations, *Release* build, no debugger attached, JIT warm-up) I get the following results on my machine:

```
naiveMax   00:06:03.3737078
Max        00:00:15.2453303
```

So `Max` is *much much* better than `naiveMax` (6 minutes! *cough*).

But how does it compare to, say, [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx)?

```
static int MaxPlinq(int[] values)
{
    return values.AsParallel().Max();
}
```

```
MaxPlinq   00:00:11.2335842
```

Not bad, saved a few seconds. Now, what about a plain, old, sequential `for` loop for comparison?

```
static int Simple(int[] values)
{
    int result = values[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        if (result < values[i]) result = values[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
Simple     00:00:05.7837002
```

I think we have a winner.

Lesson learned: [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx) is not pixie dust that you can sprinkle over your code to 
make it magically run faster. If performance matters, use the right tools and measure, *measure*, *measure*, ...

Comment: thanks dude. this is not my code, that's why I wasn't understanding. I was just reading some slides about Parallel Computation and I've found these methods. Now I see the diference is only in the time it takes fo find the max value.

Answer (score 0):

They appear to do the same thing, however they are very inefficient. The point of parallelization is to improve the speed of code that can be executed independently. Due to race conditions, discovering the maximum (as implemented here) requires an atomic semaphore/lock on the actual logic... Which means you're spinning up many threads and related resources simply to do the code sequentially anyway... Defeating the purpose of parallelization entirely.